# Creation of sequencial Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a sequence of arrays that have three variables in it.
There is an action that triggers the creation of an array and this array takes information from three different HTML textboxes.

The idea would be something like this:
- trigger
- creation of array0
- collection of data a, b and c from each text box.
- alert

- trigger
- creation of array1
- collection of data a, b and c from each text box.
- alert

-trigger
- creation of array2
etc, etc.

I have tried using the following code:

```
function sarasa() {
    window['p' + i] = new Array(document.getElementById("condition").value, 
    document.getElementById("startcondition").value, 
    document.getElementById("endcondition").value);
    i++;

    alert (p1[0]);
    alert (p0[1]);
    alert (p0[2]);
    alert (p1[0]);
    alert (p1[1]);
    alert (p1[2]);
}
```

The last alerts were to see if the code was working.

My biggest problem is that I am unsure whether I am actually achieving the alternative naming of the arrays. Any idea?

Comment: Objects can contain other objects – `var i = 0, p = [];` / `p[i] = [...];` / `p[0][0]`. This is generally preferred (more idiomatic) over defining numerous, sequenced variables.

Comment: [This suggests that ECMAScript 6.0 supports meta-programming](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/), but you don't really want to go there - as mentioned by @JonathanLonowski, a 2D array is what you are actually after.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
var myArray = [];

function sarasa() {
    var current = {condition: document.getElementById("condition").value, 
                   startCondition: document.getElementById("startcondition").value, 
                   endCondition: document.getElementById("endcondition").value};

    myArray.push(current); //or unshift()
    alert("Condition: " + current.condition + 
        ", start: " + current.startCondition + 
        ", end: " + current.endCondition );
}
```

The difference is myArray, array of objects, is defined outside the function and so its value is editable by repeated calls to the function. When the function is called the values of those fields are added to an object and added to myArray using the `.push()` function. The alert then outputs the array values in a more readable format.

Outputting the full array would just require looping over it and using a similar alert method.

Comment: I am still strugling.

Take a look:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/22f5xh64/4/

I cannot make alerts with variable contents for some reason and besides, I cannot make the 2D array work.

Comment: Martin remove all the other content for page 1,3,4, all javescript, html that doesn't relate to the inputs for medHx and the button calling medhx(). Strip it down to the absolute minimum. Implement my solution renaming the function, variables and input element id's to match your html etc and test it. Trouble shoot one thing without the complexity of all the other parts then build on it or reintroduce it back into the other code. Research recommended practice for javascript.